# %Like% Query in spring JpaRepository for property of type List<String>

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I want to write a query to find records containing specific string in a field which is
defined as as List in my Entity.

and this is my JPA Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Bank extends EntityBase<Bank> {
    .
    .
    .

    @Column(name = "sms_numbers")
    @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
    private List<String> smsNumbers;

   .
   .
   .
}
```

the SQL would be something like this :

`select * from banks where sms_numbers like '%2000400%'`

And My Repository would be something like this :

```
@Repository
interface BankRepository extends RepositoryBase<Bank> {
    
    @Query("SELECT b FROM Bank b WHERE b.smsNumbers LIKE '%2000400011%'") 
    List<Bank> findReservedSmsNumbers();   
}
```

But this code doesn't work , because Bank.smsNumbers is List Not String .

So How can I solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you Can Use Native Query instead of jpql
so your Repository would be :

```
interface BankRepository extends RepositoryBase<Bank> {

   @Query(value = "select * from banks b where b.sms_numbers like 
   concat('%',:sNumber,'%') "  , nativeQuery = true)
   List<Bank> findReservedSmsNumbers(String sNumber);
.
.
.
}
```